# Origin of Japanese particles だい(dai), かい(kai)

Tags: etymology, japanese, particles

I was wondering about the origin of these emphatic interrogative particles in Japanese. It seems very likely that they are related to the more typical forms だ and か, but what led to the postfixed /i/? Is it simply for emphasis, or is it a shortened form of よ? When did these forms start being used?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

According to [*Daijisen* and *Daijirin*](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%84-429839), the particle い *i* derives from particle や *ya* or よ *yo*. Apparently it was introduced in Early Modern Japanese.